# Windows server 2019 on ESXi 6.7 packet loss, unable to determine a source

Tags: windows, networking, vmware

Windows server 2019
ESXi 6.7
Tried both vmxnet3 and e1000e
Two two different vSwitches uplinking to two different physical switches
Tried new cabling

So starting back about a week ago I noticed my Domain controller had intermittent connectivity. FF to today when I realized it was actually a big problem due to users unable to reach DFS shares and SSLVPN users unable to authenticate.

Started a ping to 8.8.8.8, between every 10 and 45 seconds packets will drop for anywhere from 15 seconds to 2 minutes. It continues like this all day.

First off this guest shared a vswitch and the subnet with 5 other servers who all experienced zero issues.
I've tried creating a new vswitch with only this host, uplinked to a new physical server. I've changed the cabling for that vswitch. I've updated the server, I've downgraded VMware tools tow two different previous versions (one of which matched the version in use on another 2019 box that's acting just fine) all to no avail.

I've tried disabling some NIC advaced options like interrupt moderation.. nothing I've tried stops this. I've figured out that the issue must lie with Windows itself by now. But Google returns very, very little.

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Comment: Have you happened to modify some of the NIC's advanced settings? 
Example: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2039495

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up 'downgrading' from vmxnet3 to e1000 and the issue has seemed to have gone away.